# Heroku Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'

Tags: python, django, heroku

My app (called 'my_app") in Django seems to be present on the Heroku Postgres database, and my_app is running when I `python manage.py runserver` from the command line. **However** when I run my_app in Heroku I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_app'`

I also get the error `[ERROR] Exception in worker process`

I have had a look at the requirements file and procfile but could see nothing wrong. I also went through the tutorial I used to develop this app and cannot for the life of me find anything amiss.

```
Basic file structure looks like this:
```

my_app
     todo_app
           wsgi.py
           settings.py

```
 todo_list
      Procfile
      requirements.txt
      manage.py
```

Comment: show your file structure, procfile please? [This](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/go-live-with-django-project-and-heroku/) may also help

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 This is what my procfile looks like

```
web: gunicorn my_app.wsgi
```
...and this is what it says on Heroku

```
gunicorn my_app.wsgi
```

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 File structure included above as requested.

Answer (score 0):

edit your Procfile and change my_app to the path/folder where your wsgi.py file is.

```
web: gunicorn YOURFOLDER.wsgi
```

Comment: @jTkKey My question now is how do I change the 'directory' on Heroku so it also changes the `web gunicorn my_app.wsgi`? Or does Heroku change the directory **automatically**?

Comment: You can't change the dir. It's being automatically assigned. The name of the main folder doesn't matter, it will just be the root. Try:

web: gunicorn todo_app.wsgi